# Linux - Live List of Running Processes

Tags: linux, shell

Is there a way to get a list of all running processes that will auto update when new processes start running or remove themselves if they have stopped running?

Example:

`ps` gives me a list of processes running right now, but I want it to auto update, without me having to type anything else, if a new process starts running.

Comment: You do realize that on a lightly-loaded VM I'm seeing anywhere from 15 to 25 new processes created every minute. Real-time notification of process creations and deletions will flood your application.

Comment: This was just a 1 time thing that I needed to look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, tools such as `top` or `htop` show a continuously-updating list of processes (and other system information, such as overall load, available memory…).

If you only want to see your own processes, you can filter by user:

```
top -u "$(whoami)"
```

More filters are available once the commands are running; for example, to only see processes named “process a” in `top`, press <kbd>o</kbd>, then enter

```
COMMAND=process a
```

Comment: Can you give an example using that that would allow me to see all "process a" being ran?

Comment: "Include filter is missing"

Comment: What did you enter after `COMMAND=`?

Comment: "pentaho" without the double quotes.

Comment: I was able to find what I needed and I'm good now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Simply try `watch`:

```
watch -n1 'ps auxw'
```

There's more sophisticated tools like

- `htop`
- `top`
- `glances`

Comment: "TTY could not be found" when I use "ps top", can you give an example please?

Comment: @ChickenSandwichNoPickles `top` is a utility, just type `top` and press Enter.